# Find the derivative of $f$ at $2$

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives, inverse-function

Let $g$ be a real valued function defined on the interval $(-1,1)$ such that $$e^{-x}(g(x)-2e^x)=\int_0^x \sqrt{y^4+1}\,dy$$ for all $x\in (-1,1)$ and $f$ be another function such that $$f(g(x))=g(f(x))=x.$$ Then find the value of $$f'(2).$$

So, first I tried alot a then we tried it in an integration calculator but $\int_0^x \sqrt{y^4+1} \, dy$ is not possible. Next, since $f(g(x))=g(f(x))=x$ is given, therefore $f^{-1}=g$ and the vice versa. But I could not even find the dumbest idea how to do this question. Please help me out guys. Thanks!! Cheers!!

Answer (score 5):

Notice that evaluating the first equation in 0 yields $g(0)=2$.

You might then know that we are looking for $g'(0)$ because of [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Inverses_and_derivatives).

Then, by deriving the first expression using the fundamental theorem of calculus, we find:
$$
-e^{-x}g(x)+g'(x)e^{-x}=\sqrt{x^4+1}
$$
which, when evaluated in 0 yields:
$$
g'(0)-g(0)=1
$$
Then, since $g(0)=2$, you may conclude easily that $f'(2)=\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 3):

Just a small Hint: Derive $f(g(x))=x$ by chain rule:
$$(x)'=1=(f(g(x)))'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$$
Hence 
$$f'(g(x))=\frac{1}{g'(x)}.$$
So you need to find an $x$ where $g(x)=2$ and calculate $g'(x)$.